# Need to catch if a string has a number in it vb

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I want to add a catch statement to see if targetword has a number inputted into it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the word you want to guess: ")
                targetWord = Console.ReadLine
```

Comment: To create a catch statement to stop numbers being inputted

Comment: Have you attempted anything to solve this? Can you show your code? What you have now is just asking for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if a given string contains digits you can use [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim input = Console.ReadLine() ' for example: abc123def
Dim digits = input.Where(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)
If digits.Any() Then
     ' ...
End If
```

So if you want to ask the user for a new string until he enters one without digits:

```
While digits.Any()
    input = Console.ReadLine()
    digits = input.Where(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)
End While
```

Comment: Or more simply, `input.Any(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)`

Comment: @Cneaus: note that i've edited the answer to show a way how to ask the user for a new value until he gives you one without digits.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: i don't find my approach more complicated or less readable. It's also enables to output the digits if necessary(f.e. `String.Concat(digits)`).

Comment: I would always prefer a solution such as this one to a Regex solution, good show.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex :

```
If Regex.IsMatch("tes6t", "\d") Then
    Console.WriteLine("Yes")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
''' <summary>
''' Take a regular expression test pattern, a value to test the pattern against, and return true if it matches; false otherwise.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="testPattern">The regular expression against which the <paramref name="testValue"/> will be tested.</param>
''' <param name="testValue">The value that will be tested against the regular expression <paramref name="testPattern"/>.</param>
''' <returns>True if <paramref name="testValue" /> matches the regular expression <paramref name="testPattern" />.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Function ValueMatchesRegExpression(ByVal testPattern As String, ByVal testValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim regEx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(testPattern)
    ValueMatchesRegExpression = regEx.IsMatch(testValue)
End Function
```

And use it e.g. like this:

```
Debug.Print(ValueMatchesRegExpression("\d", targetWord))
```

Comment: It seems odd to wrap something so simple in your own function, when the `RegEx` class already has a shared `IsMatch` method that does the exact same thing.  In other words, your method could simply contain the single line `Return RegEx.IsMatch(testValue, testPattern)`, at which point it's nothing but a no-value-added wrapper for the shared method.  That's not to say there would never be a reason to wrap a shared method, but it seems odd to recommend it for no obvious reason in this context.

Comment: @StevenDoggart -- you're probably right, but I always try to hide complexity, even very minimal complexity.  It might be easier to remember one method call, especially if you have all your util methods in one place rather than trying to remember the namespace, syntax, etc. for `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`.  Then again, maybe not.  Depends on the situation I guess.  I always strive to pull disparate static library calls together into one utils class.